# Couldn't select the drop down value

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to select the dropdown value . Some times it selects from the drop down. some time i am getting 'Element not visible exception: element not visible'. Its visibility is false when it doesn't choose. So i tried with explicit wait but i am getting time out exception. I have tried using Javascriptexecuotr. Can anyone help me please?

```
<select class="transport-date-month ddlMonth" 
      data-bind="bookingSelect: travelDate, property: 'month', type: 'date', 
      css: { bindedValue: isBindedFromHoliday() }, 
      event: { change: setArrivalDate() }">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
    <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
    <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
    <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
    <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
    <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
    <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
    <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
    <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
    <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you make sure using browser's inspect element to see if the element's visibility is hidden due to some other element?

Comment: This might be a mundane question, but is it possible that not all Options are selectable in every case? So in other words: Are there some cases where the "travel date" is restricted to certain choices and the ones you are trying to select are therefor not visible?

Comment: This should have the javascript tag, not the java tag, correct?

Comment: public  List<WebElementFacade> getMonthDepartureList() {
        return $findAll("//select[@class='transport-date-month ddlMonth']/option");
    }  This is the web element is i used. I checked there is only one class available in that class name.

Comment: Did you try `Select()` to handle drop-down?

Comment: I am selecting some random month from the options everytime. so in my steps i have a code like this   getRandomElementFrom(flightPage.getMonthDepartureList(),1).click();

Comment: Yes i tried using Select(). Same Element not visible excption comes

Answer (score 1):

Real users are simulated via webdriver, so no interaction with invisible or hidden elements is possible. To solve it, add a div, click to div to make the dropdown visible and select an option after. Try something like:

```
<div class:"myclass">
<select id="selectID" class="transport-date-month ddlMonth"
...
</div>



WebDriverWait wdw= new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By
                .className("myclass"));
we.click();
WebElement selectElement = wdw.until(ExpectedConditions
                  .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("selectID")));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
select.selectByVisibleText("SECURITY");
```